# CELERY_IMPORTS, CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND deprecated. How to use alternative?

Tags: python, celery, deprecated

when setting celery's config like this in celery 5.0.2

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqp://localhost',
CELERY_IMPORTS=('my_tasks', 'callbacks'),
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://')
```

deprecated warnings about `CELERY_IMPORTS` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` to use

`alternative=f'Use the {_TO_NEW_KEY[setting]} instead')` in version 6.0.0 appear.

Could anyone explain how this is meant?

Answer (score 7):

just run this command

```
celery upgrade settings path/to/settings.py
```

setting file should be the where you added the celery settings

this automatically update the following to

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['**']
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "**"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "**"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "**"
```

to this

```
accept_content = ['**']
CELERY_broker_url = "**"
timezone = "**"
result_backend = "**"
```

Comment: will this also be applicable for Django-celery as well?

Answer (score 0):

So the full error message is

```
    The 'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND' setting is deprecated and scheduled for removal in
    version 6.0.0. Use the result_backend instead
```

It is recommended to replace `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` with `result_backend` since [4.0](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings).

> Version 4.0 introduced new lower case settings and setting
> organization.

So probably we will have to change the way settings are imported in the worker.

It used to be

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

And we will probably use

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

and in settings

```
result_backend='rpc://'
```

Running this command

```
celery upgrade settings --django
```

should make the necessary changes by itself though it might need some improvements as there is a ticket on GH for that.

---

There are a lot of moving parts with Celery so I'd better wait until 6.0 is released to make all the necessary changes. The way you use celery settings is how things used to be for quite some time in Django. As long as it works, stick with that. That's just my opinion, though.